# JSSE SSL: Get algorithm that is used for encryption and Integrity

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I'm using **Java JSSE SSL** to implement a simple secure application. Every thing is working fine. But SSL negotiate algorithm between client and server and they choose algorithms that they support, I dont know which algorithm they chosen.  I just need to know:

For **Authentication:**
- Which algorithm client and server have chosen, for example, **Diffie-Hellman**.
  Is there away also to force client and server to use certain algorithm.

For **Integrity (hashing):**
 - Which algorithm client and server have chosen, for example, **SHA-1**.
  Is there away also to force client and server to use certain algorithm.

For **Confidentiality (encryption):**
 - Which algorithm client and server have chosen, for example, **DES**.
  Is there away also to force client and server to use certain algorithm.

Comment: If you're using JSSE, you aren't using OpenSSL. Don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these things are specified in the various parts of the cipher suite name, which you can get via the `SSLSession`. You can affect which cipher suites are enabled via `SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites()`, but only if the peer has those ones enabled as well. In general it's not a good idea to do this. Typically the cipher suites are restricted at the server only.

Comment: when I used:  s.getSession().getCipherSuite() .. I got :TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 ... Is This for encryption, or integrity (hashing)?

Comment: The cipher suite name specifies all those things, in a specific order which is defined in RFC 2246.